# Whats the best way to recursively reverse a string in Java?

Tags: java, recursion, string

I have been messing around with recursion today. Often a programming technique that is not used enough.

I set out to recursively reverse a string. Here's what I came up with:

```
//A method to reverse a string using recursion
    public String reverseString(String s){
        char c = s.charAt(s.length()-1);
        if(s.length() == 1) return Character.toString(c);   

        return c + reverseString(s.substring(0,s.length()-1));
    }
```

My question: is there a better way in Java?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The best way is not to use recursion. These stuff are usually used to teach students the recursion concept, not actual best practices. So the way you're doing it is just fine. Just don't use recursion in Java for these kind of stuff in real world apps ;)

PS. Aside what I just said, I'd choose `""` as the base case of my recursive function:

```
public String reverseString(String s){
    if (s.length() == 0) 
         return s;

    return reverseString(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe Mehrdad just means in trivial cases like these. Although a recursive solution may actually be simpler to think of as opposed to an iterative solution, I believe it takes up much more of "the stack" to carry out the recursion. In the case of reversing a String, why the hell make a recursive solution when it's not necessary at all? Basically use recursion in situations where you definitely need it.

Comment: This will require a big stack

Answer (score 9):

If you're going to do this, you want to operate on a character array, because a String is immutable and you're going to be copying Strings all over the place if you do it that way.

This is untested and totally stream of consciousness. It probably has an OB1 somewhere. And very not-Java.

```
public String reverseString(String s)
  {
  char[] cstr = s.getChars();
  reverseCStr(cstr, 0, s.length - 1);

  return new String(cstr);
  }

/**
 * Reverse a character array in place.
 */
private void reverseCStr(char[] a, int s, int e)
  {
  // This is the middle of the array; we're done.
  if (e - s <= 0)
    return;

  char t = a[s];
  a[s] = a[e];
  a[e] = t;
  reverseCStr(a, s + 1, e - 1);
  }
```

Comment: Yup I am aware of the C/C++ ish way of using character strings, I am more interested in a Java implementation but I do like how efficient this is in comparison.

Comment: Well, this *is* written in Java. It just isn't a Java-ish way of doing things. In any case, I wouldn't do this recursively in Java *or* C, so writing C into Java didn't feel as wrong as it should have.

Answer (score 7):

You don't want to nest too deeply. Divide-and-conquer is the way to go. Also reduces total size of temporary strings and is amenable to parallelisation.

```
public static String reverseString(String str) {
    int len = str.length();
    return len<=1 ? str : (
        reverseString(str.substring(len/2))+
        reverseString(str.substring(0, len/2))
    );
}
```

(Not tested - this is stackoverflow.)

`String.concat` instead of `+` would improve performance at the expense of clarity.

Edit: Just for fun, a tail-recursion friendly version of the naive algorithm.

```
public static String reverseString(String str) {
    return reverseString("", str);
}
private static String reverseString(String reversed, String forward) {
    return forward.equals("") ? reversed : (
         reverseString(reversed+forward.charAt(0), forward.substring(1)) 
    );
}
```

Correct handling of surrogate pairs is left to the interested reader.

Comment: Not much difference... It's still O(n) operation (assuming string concatenation as an O(1) op). It just looks more like MergeSort and other stuff but it's not. The only benefit is -as you described- the depth of recursion tree.

Comment: Concatenation is O(n) (for big enough n).

Comment: I think, my method gives O(n log n) temporary string characters, whereas the linear method gives O(n^2).

Comment: Both give O(n) temporary Strings.

Comment: I see how divide and conquor is a good way to cut down the depth of the recursion tree here. However that alternative way of writing an if statement really makes me have look and concentrate a bit more. lol

Comment: Mehrdad: Yes, as I said. However, my Strings have a mean length of O(log n) instead of O(n).

Comment: On 6:28 AM May 9th dhanji tweeted that "Array insertion and deletion are constant time operations." Then "clarification: for all array sizes less than the capacity of a block memory transfer, array insertion or deletion is a O(1) operation." So O(n) is constant for n less than a constant. Blimey, but we do need to remember the size of n.

Comment: The second method has mistake at this part `reversed+forward.charAt(0)`, it should be `forward.charAt(0) + reversed`. However it will easily give `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error.

Answer (score 3):

here is my recursive reverse function that is working fine

```
public static String rev(String instr){
    if(instr.length()<=1){
        return instr;
    } else {
       return (instr.charAt(instr.length()-1)+rev(instr.substring(0,instr.length()-1)) );
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the heck of it, here's a tail-recursive method using `StringBuilder` (which is generally recommended over manipulating `String`s).

```
public String reverseString(String s_) {
    StringBuilder r = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(s_);
    r = reverseStringHelper(r, s);
    return r.toString();
}
private StringBuilder reverseStringHelper(StringBuilder r, StringBuilder s) {
    if (s.length() == 0)
        return r;
    else
        return reverseStringHelper(r.append(s.charAt(0)), s.deleteCharAt(0));
}
```

Untested, I haven't dealt with Java in many years, but this should be about right.

Comment: i like it, very cool :-)
Ofcourse we all could be lasy and use the StringBuilder reverse method but wheres the recursion in that?!lol

Comment: It would work better if (common implementations of) StringBuilder used off+len (or similar) instead of just len. Also, I don't see the point of your return value.

Comment: @Tom: pretending that these methods return new objects instead of mutating in-place makes it feel more functional ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing real code (not learning recursion), use StringBuilder's reverse() method.  The [Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) gives this example:

```
String palindrome = "Dot saw I was Tod";   
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(palindrome);
sb.reverse();  // reverse it
System.out.println(sb);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you define as "better".  :-)  Seriously, though; your solution essentially uses the maximum depth of recursion; if stack size is of a concern for your definition of "better", then you'd be better off using something like this:

```
public String reverseString(String s) {
   if (s.length() == 1) return s;
   return reverseString(s.substring(s.length() / 2, s.length() -1) + reverseString(0, s.length() / 2);
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. Is this approach of essentially cutting the problem in half and apply the base case against each half of the problem a common way of "getting the best from recursion" ?

Comment: Well, like I say, it's how you define "better".  This method isn't appreciably faster, but the highest depth of recursion (and therefore the largest stack) that you get to using this method is log(s.length()), whereas with the original proposed method, the highest depth of recursion you get to is s.length().  This way will save a little bit of stack size.

Comment: Looks like you have a stray -1, missing substring and some other stuff going on in that very long line. And it doesn't work for "".

Comment: @tom: It's just pseudocode.  I'm not writing the solution for the OP; just giving a suggestion and providing a quick idea of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've found to work and use recursive. You can pass `str.length()` as strLength argument

```
private static String reverse(String str, int strLength) {
    String result = "";
    if(strLength > 0)
        result = str.charAt(strLength - 1) + reverse(str, strLength - 1);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, since the String is immutable, the String concatenation would be more complex than it looks like.

For every concatenation, it creates a new string copying the contents of original String resulting in a linear complexity **O(n)** where **n** is the length of the string, so for m such operations it is **O(m*n)**, we can say it is of quadratic complexity **O(n^2)**.

We can use a StringBuilder which has **O(1)** complexity for each append. Below is the recursive program using StringBuilder. This uses only n/2 stack frames, so it has less space complexity than the normal recursive call which would be like `s.charAt(s.length-1) + reverse(s.subString(0, s.length-2);`

```
public class StringReverseRecursive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "lasrever gnirts fo noitatnemelpmi evisrucer a si sihT";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        reverse(s, sb, 0, sb.length() - 1);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }

    public static void reverse(String s, StringBuilder sb, int low, int high) {
        if (low > high)
            return;
        sb.setCharAt(low, s.charAt(high));
        sb.setCharAt(high, s.charAt(low));
        reverse(s, sb, ++low, --high);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely how I'd go about recursively reversing a string (although it might be nice to extend it to the case of an empty string in your condition.)  I don't think there is any fundamentally better way.

EDIT:  It may be more efficient to operate on a character array and pass a "cutoff" length down the chain of recursion, if you get my drift, rather than making substrings.  However, this is not really worth nitpicking about, since it's not a terribly efficient technique in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

As [Mehrdad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859562/whats-the-best-way-to-recursively-reverse-a-string-in-java/859572#859572) noted, it's best not to use recursion. If you do use it, though, you might as well keep both the first and last character each call, thus halving the number of recursive calls. That is,

```
public String reverseString(String s){
    int len = s.length();

    if (len <= 1) {
        return s;
    }

    char fst = s.charAt(0);
    char lst = s.charAt(len - 1);

    return lst + reverseString(s.substring(1, len - 2)) + fst;
}
```

This also handles the case of the empty string. Perhaps passing along a StringBuilder with the appropriate capacity would speed things up even more, but that's left as an exercise to the reader ;)

Comment: This fails on string "a" for example. Why it's better than the original?

Comment: s/==/<=/ :). It's 'better' because it requires half the number of recursive calls.

Comment: I like it because it halves the recursive stack,
but as stated, it wud not work with a string like "a". Perhaps it would be possible to use this method with tail recursion as above, validate the string first then apply the recursion. As I can see you understood that no one would care if you reversed strings of one char, as the reverse is the same. Am I right on my assumption?

Comment: I'm at a loss why the corrected version does not work for "a": it has length 1, and hence is returned unchanged. I guess I don't understand your last remark.

Answer (score 0):

You capture the basic idea, but extracting the last character doesn't improve clarity. I'd prefer the following, others might not:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(reverse("a"));
        System.out.println(reverse("ab"));
        System.out.println(reverse("abc"));
    }


    public final static String reverse(String s)
    {
        // oft-repeated call, so reduce clutter with var
        int length = s.length();

        if (length <= 1)
            return s;
        else
            return s.substring(length - 1) + reverse(s.substring(0, length - 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an external variable, and add 1 by 1 all chars:

```
    public static String back="";

public static String reverseString(String str){


    if(str.length()==0){

        return back;

    }else {

        back+=str.charAt(str.length()-1);

        lees(str.substring(0,str.length()-1));


        return back;

    }
```

}

Comment: I think I did try something like this in one of my first attempts.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/1612155) is my immutable version:

```
 String reverse(String str) {
    if(str.length()<2) return str;
    return  reverse(str.substring(1)) +str.charAt(0);
}
```

and tail recursive version:

```
 String reverseTail(String str) {
    if(str.length()<2) return str;
    return str.charAt(str.length()-1)+ reverseTail(str.substring(0,str.length()-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

In this context, this is totally unnecessary, but you can simulate recursion and avoid recursion depth issues if you make your own stack.

You can iterative implement recursion, which may be necessary when you have algorithms which are inherently recursive, but also need to run them for big problem sizes.

```
String recIterReverse (String word){

    Stack <String> stack = new Stack <String> ();
    stack.push(word);
    String result = "";

    while (!stack.isEmpty()){
        String temp = stack.pop();
        result = temp.charAt(0) + result;

        if (temp.length() > 1){
        stack.push(temp.substring(1));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

function call:

```
    //str:string to be reversed,i=0,j=str.length-1


    public void reverseString(String str,int i,int j)
    {

     if(i==j)
        {
         System.out.println(str);
         return;
        }

     char x=str.charAt(i);
     str=str.replace(str.charAt(i),str.charAt(j));
     str=str.replace(str.charAt(j),x);
     i++;j--;
     reverseString(str,i,j);
    }
```

this method works too..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
public class reverse2
{
    public static void main(String name)
    {
    String revname=new StringBuffer(name).reverse().toString();
    System.out.println("original string " + name + " and the reverse of it is " + revname);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String rev(String name){
    if(name.length()>=1){
    System.out.print(name.charAt(name.length()-1)); 
    return rev(name.substring(0,name.length()-1));
    }
    else{
        return ""+name.substring(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String rev="";

public String reverseString(String s){
        if (s.length()==0) return "";
        return rev+s.substring(s.length()-1,s.length())+reverseString(s.substring(0, s.length()-1));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String reverseString (String s) {

    if (s != null && s.length () > 0 ) {
        rev = rev + s.substring (s.length () - 1);
        reverseString (s.substring (0, s.length () - 1));
    }
    return rev;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringUtility {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringUtility stringUtility = new StringUtility();

    String input = "santosh123";
    int middle = input.length() / 2;
    middle = middle - 1;
    System.out.println(stringUtility.stringReverse(input, middle));
}

public String stringReverse(String input, int middle) {

    if (middle == -1) {

        System.out.println("if");
        return input;

    } else {

        System.out.println("else");
        input = swapChar(input, middle);
        middle = middle - 1;
        return stringReverse(input, middle);

    }

}

private String swapChar(String input, int middle) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(input);
    char begin = str.charAt(middle);
    int endIndex = input.length() - middle - 1;
    char end = str.charAt(endIndex);
    str.setCharAt(middle, end);
    str.setCharAt(endIndex, begin);
    System.out.println(str + "  " + middle + "  " + endIndex);
    return str.toString();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think less code is good then....

```
static String reverse(String str){
    return str.length()>=2 ? str.charAt(str.length()-1) + reverse(str.substring(0,str.length()-1)) : str ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are about 20 answers already but I'll just throw in my recursive algorithm as well. It may be a little verbose but it is at least readable.

```
public static String reverseString(String str) {
   return reverseString("", str);
}

private static String reverseString(String result, String original) {
   if (original.length() == 0) {
      return result;
   } else {
      int length = original.length();
      String lastLetter = original.substring(length - 1, length);
      original = original.substring(0, length - 1);
      return reverseString(result + lastLetter, original);
   }
}
```

The code basically recursively takes the end of the string and moves it in front. For example if the string we want to reverse is "jam," then each time the helper method is called, result and original strings are as follows:

```
// result:  original:
// ""       jam
// m        ja
// ma       j
// maj      ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse String using the recursive method call.

> Sample Code

```
public static String reverseString(String s) {
    if (s.length() == 0) {
        return s;
    }
    else {
        return s.charAt(s.length() - 1) + reverseString(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please add some explanation why this is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution,I saw in many solutions above we are getting the string length but ideally we don't need that. The Zen is to use recursion, just chop the first char of string and pass the rest to recursive method. Yay!! we got the solution.

```
private static void printReverse(String str) {
            if (!str.isEmpty()) {
                String firstChar = str.substring(0, 1); //Get first char of String
                String newstr = str.substring(0, 0) + str.substring(1); // Get remaining string
                printReverse(newstr); // Recursion magic
                System.out.print(firstChar); //Output
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static String reverse(String s){

    int n = s.length()-1;

    if(n >=0)
    return  s.substring(s.length()-1)+ReverseString(s.substring(0,n--));
    else return "";
}
```