# Reversing a string without using any built in methods

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Printing reverse of any String without using any predefined function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612976/printing-reverse-of-any-string-without-using-any-predefined-function)

Please advise how to reverse a string without using built in methods. I want to use only string class, please advise let say there is a string "john is a boy" and print "yob a si nhoj".

Comment: You need use a mutable sequence of characters.

Comment: How about something like this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/reverse-string.  Use an array?

Comment: Vote to close - this question can be answered by a thousand other pages on the internet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will return the string backwards. all you have to do is iterate through the string backwards and add it to another string.

you do this using a for loop, but first check if the string has a greater lenght than 0.

Java Strings have a method "charAt(index)" which return a single character on the position of the string, where position 0 is the first character. so if you would like to reverse "Boy" you would start on letter 2, then 1, and then 0, and add them all together into a new String, resulting in "yoB".

```
public static String reverseString(String inString) {
    String resultString = "";//This is the resulting string, it is empty but we will add things in the next for loop
    if(inString.length()>0) {//Check the string for a lenght greater than 0
        //here we set a number to the strings lenght-1 because we start counting at 0
        //and go down to 0 and add the character at that position in the original string to the resulting one
        for(int stringCharIndex=inString.length()-1;stringCharIndex>=0;stringCharIndex--) {
            resultString+=inString.charAt(stringCharIndex);
        }
    }
    //finaly return the resulting string.
    return resultString;
}
```

Comment: @mprivat: agreed, although the student could find many, *many* explicit solutions by doing any amount of searching the web.

Comment: oops did not see the homework tag. i was just trying to help. no reason to downvote without warning. sorry

Comment: @mprivat You [shouldn't downvote people](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/145982) who answer homework questions either

Comment: Thanks. at least i try to explain how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through all the characters in your string and prepend them to a StringBuffer using the insert(0, char) method. Then at the end of the iteration, your StringBuffer will be the reversed string.

Comment: "I want to use only string class"