# How to reverse String Array without using inbuilt function like String Builder and String Buffer

Tags: java, arrays

Please find the most frequently ask java question on interview ie "Program to reverse String Array without using the inbuilt function"

```
package program;

public class StringReverse {

String[] input={"Welcome"};
int i;
char rev11[];

void ReversStr(){

    char rev11[] = input[i].toCharArray();//since we know that we cant traversed String Array ,hence we have to change String array into Char array
    System.out.println("Array after reverse:");
    for (int i = rev11.length-1; i>=0; i--)
        System.out.print(rev11[i]);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringReverse obj=new StringReverse();
    obj.ReversStr();


}

}
```

Comment: What's your question? Whether that's a bad interview question? Yes, it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing reverse of any String without using any predefined function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612976/printing-reverse-of-any-string-without-using-any-predefined-function)

Comment: Calling `toCharArray` rather than `charAt` would prompt an immediate question; why? Printing out to console rather than returning a `String` that has been reversed is, I would say, a rather massive issue - probably a fail. But this question is so trivial that it could only ever be used as part of automated testing and the usefulness of that is questionable at best...

Comment: @ Boris the Spider we annot use  method charAt(int) in the type String bcos it is not applicable for the given arguments ()

Comment: @NishantGupta if you check my program is specially for [String Array],i know ,same can be done with String type also.

Comment: Don't understand your point. You current code copies the `char[]` inside the `String` by calling `toCharArray` - using `charAt` doesn't do that as you can access `char` by index.

Comment: A more advanced question would be: how do you deal with surrogate pairs?

Answer (score 0):

First: probably a new reversed array is required.

In that such a reversing has one/two pitfalls:

```
void reverse(String[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length / 2; ++i) {
        int complementaryI = a.length - 1 - i;
        String temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[complementaryI];
        a[complementaryI] = temp;
    }
}
```

The beginner's error being `i < a.length`.

If not in-situ reversed, but a new array is required, but the same code must be altered, one must copy the middle element of odd length array, or loop till `a.length`.

Comment: Would prefer a `String reverse(String input)` method. If it's going to be an in-place reverse, wouldn't you take `char[]`? But given that `String` is immutable, you would always have to build a new one, so I don't see the purpose of the in place method.