# Recursively reverse a sequence in Clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure

I want to reverse a sequence in Clojure without using the `reverse` function, and do so recursively.

Here is what I came up with:

```
(defn reverse-recursively [coll]
  (loop [r (rest coll)
         acc (conj () (first coll))]
    (if (= (count r) 0)
      acc
      (recur (rest r) (conj acc (first r))))))
```

Sample output:

```
user> (reverse-recursively '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
(6 5 4 3 2 1)
user> (reverse-recursively [1 2 3 4 5 6])
(6 5 4 3 2 1)
user> (reverse-recursively {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
([:c 3] [:b 2] [:a 1])
```

Questions:

1. Is there a more concise way of doing this, i.e. without loop/recur?
2. Is there a way to do this without using an "accumulator" parameter in the loop?

---

References:

[Whats the best way to recursively reverse a string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859562/whats-the-best-way-to-recursively-reverse-a-string-in-java)

http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/4e7a4bfb0d71a508?pli=1

Comment: Were you possibly attempting [this 4clojure problem](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/23)? :)

Comment: No, I was not. "Reverse a string recursively" is a very common interview problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

- You don't need to count.  Just stop when the remaining sequence is empty.
- You shouldn't pre-populate the `acc`, since the original input may be empty (and it's more code).
- Destructuring is cool.

```
(defn reverse-recursively [coll]
  (loop [[r & more :as all] (seq coll)
         acc '()]
    (if all
      (recur more (cons r acc))
      acc)))
```

As for `loop`/`recur` and the `acc`, you need some way of passing around the working reversed list.  It's either `loop`, or add another param to the function (which is really what `loop` is doing anyway).

Or use a higher-order function:

```
user=> (reduce conj '() [1 2 3 4])
(4 3 2 1)
```

Comment: regarding "use a higher-order function" check out `(source reverse)`

Comment: repl abort when this function apply map ({:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})  .

Comment: Well, technically my question was "reverse a sequence" not "reverse anything, including a map" so I think this problem doesn't exclude it.  Here is the error, btw: `Clojure> (reverse-recursively {:a 1 :b 2})`
`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: nth not supported on this type: PersistentArrayMap`

Comment: Also, it looks like loop / recur is of course needed for tail recursion, but it is considered a "code smell" in Clojure: http://twoguysarguing.wordpress.com/2010/07/26/7-rules-for-writing-clojure-programs/

Comment: @noahz Actually the article says "loop/recur is *not* a code smell, but be suspicious of it". I guess what they mean is prefer map, reduce etc in general, but they won't always provide a solution.

Comment: The solution to allow anything to work with the above function (e.g., maps), is to initialize the loop with `(seq coll)`, instead of just `coll`.

Comment: FWIW `(reverse-recursively ())` will return `(nil)`. This problem is also solved by using `(seq coll)`, although I prefer to not destructure in the `loop` (which introduces a fairly useless `:as`), but instead to have an `if-let` inside the loop.

Comment: The `:as all` is necessary to check the terminating condition without introducing nil/false-as-element problems. Edit: nvm, I figured out what you meant.  I usually do that too but I've been on a destructuring kick lately.

Comment: Loop is not a recursion…

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of exhaustivenes, there is one more method using `into`. Since into internally uses `conj` it can be used as follows :

```
(defn reverse-list 
  "Reverse the element of alist."
  [lst]
  (into '() lst))
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes to question 1, this is what I came up with for my answer to the recursion koan (I couldn't tell you whether it was good clojure practice or not).

```
(defn recursive-reverse [coll]
    (if (empty? coll)
        []
        (conj (recursive-reverse (rest coll)) (first coll) )))
```

Comment: Well, try this: `(recursive-reverse (apply str (seq (take 100000 (repeat "foo")))))`

Comment: Fair enough, I just got to the last part of that koan where the factorial function overflows if you don't do it without the loop/recur construct. So I guess now I can say that it's not good practice :) - cheers!

Comment: This is really elegant!

Answer (score 2):

In current version of Clojure there's a built-in function called `rseq`. For anyone who passes by.

Comment: `rseq` requires the input sequence to be `Reversible`, which makes it generally unsuitable (doesn't work with `cons` lists, with `PersistentList`, with `LazySeq`, with strings). It is meant as an optimization for sequences which can be reversed in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn my-rev [col]
  (loop [ col col
          result []]
        (if (empty? col)
            result
            (recur (rest col) (cons (first col) result)))))
```

**Q1.**

The JVM can not optimize the recursion, a recursive function that would directly and stack overflow. Therefore, in Clojure, which uses the loop/recur. So, without using a function that recur deep recursion can not be defined. (which is also used internally to recur as a function trampoline.)

**Q2.**

a recursive function by recur,   must be tail-recursive. If the normal recursive function change to tail-recursive function, so there is a need to carry about the value of a variable is required as the accumulator.

Comment: The order of a sequence of map does not change the execution. But order is due to be implemented.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. "Order is due to be implemented?"

Comment: @noahz, (rev {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})->([:c 3] [:b 2] [:a 1]) is not necessarily so. my result by Clojure1.3.0 is ([:b 2] [:c 3] [:a 1])

Comment: Ah, because `PersistentArrayMap` in Clojure is unordered like `java.util.HashMap` ? That's non-intuitive.

Comment: I know. The map is in general not determined the order knows. In order that they were inserted as shown in the example must necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn reverse-seq [sss]
  (if (not (empty? sss))
    (conj (reverse-seq (rest sss)) (first sss))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn recursive-reverse [coll]
  (if (empty? coll)
    ()
    (concat (vector (peek coll)) (recursive-reverse (pop coll )))
  )
)
and test:
user=> (recursive-reverse [1])       
(1)
user=> (recursive-reverse [1 2 3 4 5])
(5 4 3 2 1)
```