# Can I use the clojure 'for' macro to reverse a string?

Tags: clojure

This is a follow up to my question ["Recursively reverse a sequence in Clojure"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395064/recursively-reverse-a-sequence-in-clojure).

Is it possible to reverse a sequence using the Clojure "for" macro?  I'm trying to better understand the limitations and use-cases of this macro.

Here is the code I'm starting from:

```
((defn reverse-with-for [s] 
    (for [c s] c))
```

Possible?

If so, I assume the solution may require wrapping the `for` macro in some expression that defines a mutable var, or that the body-expr of the for macro will somehow pass a sequence to the next iteration (similar to `map`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you could reverse a string with for:

```
(defn reverse-with-for [s] 
    (apply str
        (for [i (range (dec (count s)) -1 -1)]
            (get s i))))
```

Note that this code is mutation free. It's the same as:

```
(defn reverse-with-map [s] 
    (apply str
        (map (partial get s) (range (dec (count s)) -1 -1))))
```

A simpler solution would be:

```
(apply str (reverse s))
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing that I was looking for.  Bonus for being mutation-free. Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if String supported `rseq` so that you could do this without the overhead of traversing the string for reversal.

Comment: @amalloy Yeah. I found your mailing list post about this while I was writing this answer and Googled for *clojure string rseq*. Reversing a string is not something you have to do so often though.

Answer (score 7):

Clojure `for` macro is being used with arbitrary Clojure sequences.

These sequences may or may not expose random access like vectors do. So, in general case, you do not have access to the last element of a Clojure sequence without traversing all the way to it, which would make making a pass through it in reverse order not possible.

I'm assumming you had something like this in mind (Java-like pseudocode):

```
for(int i = n-1; i--; i<=0){
   doSomething(array[i]);
}
```

In this example we know array size `n` in advance and we can access elements by its index. With Clojure sequences we don't know that. In Java it makes sense to do that with arrays and ArrayLists. Clojure sequences are however much more like linked lists - you have an element, and a reference to next one.

Btw, even if there were a <strike>(probably non-idiomatic)</strike>* way to do that, its time complexity would be something like O(n^2) which is just not worth the effort compared to much easier solution in the linked post which is O(n^2) for lists and a much better O(n) for vectors (and it is quite elegant and idiomatic. In fact, the official `reverse` has that implementation).

EDIT:

A general advice: Don't try to do imperative programming in Clojure, it wasn't designed for it. Although many things may seem strange or counter-intuitive (as opposed to well known idioms from imperative programming) once you get used to the functional way of doing things it is a lot, and I mean *a lot* easier.

Specifically for this question, despite the same name Java (and other C-like) `for` and Clojure `for` are not the same thing! First is an actual loop - it defines a flow control. The second one is a *comprehension* - look at it conceptually as a higher function of a sequence and a function *f* to be done *for* each of its element, which returns another sequence of *f(element)* s. Java `for` is a statement, it doesn't evaluate to anything, Clojure `for` (as well as anything else in Clojure) is an expression - it evaluates to the sequence of *f(element)* s.

Probably the easiest way to get the idea is to play with sequence functions library: http://clojure.org/sequences. Also, you can solve some problems on http://www.4clojure.com/. The first problems are very easy but they gradually get harder as you progress through them.

<sub>*As shown in Alexandre's answer the solution to the problem in fact is idiomatic and quite clever. Kudos for that! :)</sub>

Comment: Understood. But I imagine you could so something gnarly like mutate a var defined outside the `for`.  But then, `doseq` is probably more (in)appropriate.

Comment: @noahz: I guess you *could* do something like that. My edit is referring to that part. But then you are using mutable state in an imperative algorithm. Following that trail of thoughts, you *could* as well write a pure Java code in actual Java and call it via interop. I'm not always against imperative mutating code. I just think it is more easily done in raw Java. Especially since interop works so well.

Comment: Check out Alexandre's solution.  Performance is awful but it was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, as Goran said, `for` is not a statement - it is an expression, namely sequence comprehension. It construct sequences by iteration through other sequences. So in the form it is meant to be used it is pure function (without side-effects). `for` can be seen as enhanced `map` infused with `filter`. Because of this it cannot be used to hold iteration state as e.g. `reduce` do.

Secondly, you can express sequence reversal using `for` and mutable state, e.g. using an atom, which is rough equivalent (not taking into account its concurrency properties) of java variable. But doing so you are facing several problems:

1. You are breaking main language paradigm so you will definitely get worse looking and behaving code.
2. Since all clojure mutable state cells are designed to be thread-safe, they all use some kind of illegal concurrent modification protection, and there is no ability to remove it. Consequently, you will get poorer performance characteristics.
3. In this particular case, like Goran said, sequences are one of the wide-used Clojure abstractions. For example, there are lazy sequences, which could be potentially infinite, so you just cannot walk them to the end. You certainly will have difficulties trying to work with such sequences with imperative techniques.

So don't do it, at least in Clojure :)

EDIT: I forgot to mention it. `for` returns lazy sequence, so you have to evaluate it in some way in order to apply all state mutations you do in it. Another reason not to do so :)

Comment: actually, atoms are quite fast, in uncontended code, they're a single compare-and-set java call.  https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Atom.java   In my testing, they're about 20x slower than (inc 1)

Comment: map+filter is actually still not as powerful as `for`. `for` is more like a (possibly repeated) application of `mapcat`, which in fact is equally powerful. Consider writing `(for [x (range 10) y [:x x]] y)` as a `map` operation: you can't do it, because you want to return twice as many elements as you're given.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I didn't know about such splice functionality of `for`. I wrote about equivalence of `for` and map+filter thinking about the similar construction in Scala, about which I read it is equivalent to map+filter.