# How to write a recursive method that takes a string as an argument and returns that string turned inside out?

Tags: java

You may assume that the argument string is non-null, not empty, and doesn't contain any spaces or punctuation.

This is the code that I have so far I think you first might have to reverse it so I tried to reverse at least one half but obviously you can tell that I dont know what I'm doing and how would you write this recursively.

```
public static String reverseString(String s) {
    return new (StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString()/2);
}
```

SO example: if the string was "abcde" it should return "cbdae"
if the string was "pq" then return"pq"
if the string was "321123" then return "112233"

How can I implement this?

Comment: This sounds like homework. if so you should mark it as such.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the best way to recursively reverse a string in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859562/whats-the-best-way-to-recursively-reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Judging from his "reverse" and "/2", probably ABCDEF becoming CBAFED?

Comment: You need to do some research on recursive functions. But, even before you do that you need to think about how you would do this step-by-step on paper, it will make the solution much easier to see,

Answer (score 0):

While writing a recursive method, you need to keep in the following 2 aspects

- Terminating logic
- Repeating logic

For your present problem, the terminating case will be that either the string is null or has only 1 character. In both these cases, the value returned will be the string itself.

The repeating logic in your case is that the first letter of your string needs to be appended AFTER the reverse of the rest of the string.

Comment: Why are you giving the OP the answer? From the post this is clearly homework.

Comment: I know. I saw the comments after I posted. Have removed the answer