# Is it possible to reverse each line of a file using a BufferedReader?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Say I am importing a file, which contains lines. I would like to reverse this file by recursively outputting the tail of sequence, followed by the head of the sequence. Is this possible using a BufferedReader? Or would I first need to import these lines into a list? I have to do it with recursion.

So for example, I have a file containing the following:

```
Hi
My
Name
Is
Mark
```

I would like it to output in reverse order in another file:

```
Mark
Is
Name
My
Hi
```

I think I have created the recursive method correctly, although it compiles fine, but the output file is empty after the program is run.

```
public void Reverse(BufferedReader br, PrintWriter pw) {
    try {
        String headLine = br.readLine();
        if (headLine != null) {
            Reverse(br, pw);
            pw.println(br.readLine());
        }
        pw.println(headLine);      
    } //try
```

Comment: Could you give an example so that we understand what you are exactly asking? :)

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such

Comment: Please show some of your code.  Folks aren't going to write it for you.

Comment: @Gray added the recursive method above.

Comment: Please edit your code and show us a bit of `Reverse` or is that it?

Comment: @Gray I have added the complete code for `Reverse` above :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10599/discussion-between-akshai5050-and-gray)

Answer (score 2):

> It has to be using recursion

Here is a recursive solution:

1. read one line from the file;
2. recursively reverse the remainder of the file;
3. write out the line read in step 1.

Since this is homework, I leave it to you to figure out how to translate this into actual Java code.

Comment: It has to be using recursion :)

Comment: Thanks, I think I have the right idea.. just unsure how to read the tail line recursively. This is the code I have: `String headLine = input.readLine();
      String currentLine;
      if (headLine != null)
      {
        Reverse(input, output);
 output.println(currentLine);
      }//if
      output.println(headLine);`

Comment: @akshai5050: You've got the right idea. I am not sure I understand what it is exactly that you're having difficulty with.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can read and output the last line of the file on each recursive call in order for the lines to be outputted in reverse.

Comment: @akshai5050: You don't need to. What you have is sufficient (**except that `headLine` and `currentLine` should be one and the same**). I suggest you try to experiment with the code you've got.

Comment: I've made a slight change, instead of doing `output.println(currentLine)` I am now doing `output.println(input.readLine());` It complies fine, but when i check the output file, it is empty.

Comment: I've tried making the headLine and currentLine the same, but that still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of outright giving you the solution, you probably don't want to think of this in terms of head and tail.  Think of it in terms of lines and then read the answers and discussions to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859562/whats-the-best-way-to-recursively-reverse-a-string-in-java).  You can apply the same technique.

Answer (score 0):

By all means read everything into a `LinkedList` and then throw recursion on it. Only, Collection Framework is a very cumbersome match for this kind of work.