# String IndexOut Of Bounds Exception error in java

Tags: java

I have made a program for reversing the words of an input string
There's an error code:

> ```
>                    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:String index out of range: 17
>                    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:695)
>                    at Rev.main(Rev.java:14)
> ```

The Main Program Code is:

> ```
> import java.io.*;
> class Rev
> {
>  public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
>   {
>     BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
>     System.out.println("Enter String");
>     String a=br.readLine();
>     a=" "+a+" ";
>     int x=a.length();
>     String b;
>     for(int z=a.length()-1;z>=0;z--)
>     {
>      if (a.charAt(z)==' ')
>      {
>       b=a.substring(z,x);
>       System.out.print(b+" ");    
>       a=a.replace(b,"");
>      }
>     }
>   }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: You shouldn't modify `a` in your for loop as the for condition is based on it.

Comment: You might find that StringBuilder is a better starting point.

Comment: [Here is some discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859562/whats-the-best-way-to-recursively-reverse-a-string-in-java) on this topic with multiple examples of implementations that you might find helpful.

Comment: Whenever you do `a=a.replace(b,"")`, your string gets shorter by an arbitrary amount. Do you realize that this method replaces **all occurrences of b** in the string? But, even if it replaced only one occurrence, the same error would appear. You must completely rethink your loop.

Comment: @HyperAnthony That's a question about how to do it recursively. This is a bad and not very intuitive way to reverse a string.

Comment: @millimoose That very point is actually brought up in the very helpful discussion in the aforementioned link. ;)  Taking the entire discussion (the multiple answers included) into account, I think OP would gain a lot of insight into this problem.

Comment: @HyperAnthony Yes, but I'd say a good answer here would ideally also include explaining why the OP's code is problematic. I'm not saying your link isn't useful, just that it's not really sufficient.

Comment: @millimoose I agree - that's why this is merely a comment.

Comment: b=a.substring(z,x);  replace it with b=a.substring(z), since your code implies you are trying to get substring till the last index.

Answer (score 1):

If a Java professional needed to solve your problem, he'd do it in just a couple of lines:

```
final List<String> words = Arrays.asList(input.split(" "));
Collections.reverse(words);
for (String word : words) System.out.print(word + " ");
System.out.println();
```

If you are doing this as an excercise and want to implement it yourself, you may still consider using the same basic idea. For example, run through your string and collect all positions of a space into a `List<Integer>`. Then work through that list backwards, using `input.substring(list.get(i), list.get(i-1))`.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you should try:

```
int x=a.length()-1;
```

the substring is causing the error

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you split the input by space and store in an array and reverse the array?

Comment: This is a question, not an answer. (Good suggestion, but you should show code and link to Javadocs, especially considering the OP's likely skill level..)

Answer (score 0):

You know the string index you're specifying is wrong.  You know where the error's occurring.  Add `System.out.println` calls to print the sting index and the length of the string just before the errant statement, and at other critical points in your code.  Debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well i know this is not the answer to your question, but why don't you try StringBuilder or StringBuffer method know as reverse()

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello");

sb.reverse();
```