# Java recursion reverse string

Tags: java, recursion

Hi I am trying understand the below recursion method but it seems too confusing. I know that the reversePrint method calls it self but my problem is,  the first time it runs it should print bcdef + a = bcdef. Here is where I get confused, the next time it runs b becomes the charAt(0)... so where is a?? Do they get stored temporally in somewhere? Can someone please help me understanding it. Many thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println(reversePrint("abcdef"));
}

public static String reversePrint(String s) {
    if (s.length() <= 1) {
        return s;
    }
    return reversePrint(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the best way to recursively reverse a string in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859562/whats-the-best-way-to-recursively-reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: go through with your compliler. it will tell you everything

Comment: Try to run it step by step in debug mode. It will be illustrative.

Comment: 'a' is in the very first call to s.charAt(0). Think of it this way. To reverse a String, create a new String with the first character at the end of the reverse of the remaining characters. And so on...

Comment: Regarding the temporary variable stuff youre confused about, take a look at how stack frames work http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/recursion/explanation-of-recursion/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's work through the example a bit:

You start by calling `reversePrint("abcdef")`.  To abbreviate, I'll just write this as `rev(abcdef)`.

```
rev(abcdef)

= rev(bcdef) a     // Take the beginning (a) and put it on the end.
= (rev(cdef) b) a 
= ((rev(def) c) b) a
= (((rev(ef) d) c) b) a
= ((((rev(f) e) d) c) b) a

= fedcba
```

At each step, we evaluate `rev` on a substring of the original.  So first we evaluate `rev(abcdef)`. But to work that out, we need to evaluate `rev(bcdef)`, and for that we need `rev(cdef)` and so on.

We work this out all the way down to `rev(f)`, which is just `f`.  Then we concatenate one string onto the next, and we end up with `rev(abcdef) = fedcba`.

I'd recommend watching [Khan Academy's video on recursion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zg-ddPbzcKM) (using the Fibonacci Sequence).  He does a great job stepping through this.

Comment: @user3545850 No problem. Make sure you take a look at [this video on recursion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zg-ddPbzcKM) if you're still having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Here first it is separating a string between first character and remaining string and this process is repeating until the length of the string is less than or equal to 1.

```
abcdef 
  bcdef   a
   cdef   b
     def  c
       ef d
        f e
          f
```

terminated again compiler goes up the stack then final result is generated.

fedcba...
hope it is clear.