# Reverse a String in Java recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I have referenced [Whats the best way to recursively reverse a string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859562/whats-the-best-way-to-recursively-reverse-a-string-in-java) for a solution but there are subtle differences between my solution and the correct solution that I do not understand.

I am trying to reverse the strings in args given through the command line. This is my recursive method to reverse a String (almost identical). However, I am running into a StackOverflowException. I was wondering why that was? Is it because my method is a static method while theirs isn't?

```
public static String reverse(String word) {
    if (word.length() == 1) {
        return word;
    } else {
        return reverse(word.substring(1) + word.charAt(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Take the word.charAt(0) out of the parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

Everytime you call reverse, the length of the string doesn't change. If you change your return statement to:

```
return reverse(word.substring(1))  + word.charAt(0);
```

Each time you call reverse, the length of word will be one character shorter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String reverseString(String str) {

        if (str.length() == 1) {
            return str;
        } else {
            reverse += str.charAt(str.length() - 1)
                    + reverseString(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
            return reverse;
        }
    }
```